# Real-time filer applied on an UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, filter, core-image

I am trying to add a filter view on an UIView instance called srcView. What I am doing is like below:

```
//Generate the screenshot of srcView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(srcView.bounds.size);
[srcView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1); // convert to jpeg
image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

//A custom filter effect applied on a image
imageView.image = [image boxblurImageWithBlur:kStyleBlur];
```

It works fine. But when device rotating, since the srcView will relayout its subviews, what I am doing is to re-generate the screenshot of srcView after device rotated(`UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`), so the imageView seems to 'jump' a little bit. Is there a way to avoid it 'jump'?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be willing to implement an animation ?
You could try:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159/2);
imageView.transform = transform;

// Repositions and resizes the imageview.
CGRect contentRect = //the new rect
imageView.bounds = contentRect;
```

Comment: Thanks @Luke! I think you misunderstood my problem. The content of imageView(image), is based on the content of srcView. When rotate happens, the srcView will relayout its subViews, which means its content changes. So the content of imageView needs to be re-generated, which will make imageView's rotate animation jump.

Comment: Yes, I missunderstood you, sorry. Could you explain what is this jump you are talking about ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The content of imageView depend on the content of srcView, so when rotation happens, I have to wait until rotation finished, then re-generate the content of imageView. But you know, when rotation happens, the imageView has its own animation to rotate itself according to its `autoresizingMask`. So, the process to "re-generate" the content of imageView after rotation finished will be seen as a jump.